# ACS does not postback the security token to the return url

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, acs, azure-acs

i have set up a test app successfully using .NET4.0 + ACS2.0 with standard login page.
Everything just work fine. I click my login button, get redirected to acs loginpage and the security token is successfully posted to localhost:7777/Account/SignIn
So far, so good.

Now, I have set up the same test app as above in .NET4.5 (with System.IdentityModel...) and ACS2.0 with standard login page. I followed the wizard Identity & Access:

```
<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="http://localhost:7777/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="1111111111111111111111111111111111111" name="https://***********.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://*************.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://localhost:7777/" reply="http://localhost:7777/Account/SignIn" requireHttps="false" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SignIn(FormCollection forms)
{
    var ip = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.IdentityProvider();
    var ni = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.NameIdentifier();
```

Now, when I click my loginbutton, I get successfully redirected to the standard loginpage, but ACS never sends a postback to my SignIn page... Is this a bug in the new System.IdentityModel...? or do I miss something.

Comment: What do you mean by "ACS never sends postback to my SignIn page"? Please explain! Does it redirect you to your site, but different page? Does it show error? Does it show the login page again? Does it do something else?

Comment: In ACS controlpanel I set ReturnUrl to localhost:7777/Account/SignIn so the security token can be handled by that actioncontroller, but ACS is redirecting to the homepage localhost:7777/. No errors, only a wrong redirect.

Comment: Have you used fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/) before? Install it, if you haven't and trace all the calls from the authenticating with selected IdP to what exactly ACS sends to your page. Inspect the http traffic you may discover amazing things. It is hard to tell you what is wrong without full traces. This you will also make sure that ACS posts to the default, but not posting to the Account controller and then the Account Controller to your default home controller. Also is your Authentication Mode set to "None" instead of "Forms" in web.config?

Comment: did you find a fix for this, I am hitting the same issue.